# How to encrypt an object in Azure using KeyVaultClient (JAVA)

Tags: java, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

Normally encryption happens for byte Arrays plainText.

```
promise = keyVaultClient.encryptAsync(keyId.getBaseIdentifier(), JsonWebKeyEncryptionAlgorithm.RSAOAEP, plainText); 
result = promise.get(); 
cipherText = result.getResult();
```

Where KeyVaultClient object encrypt byte[] and returns Future.

How to encrypt an object?

Answer (score 0):

You can see soucre code of `encryptAsync` method as below in [azure keyvault java sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-keyvault-java/blob/master/azure-keyvault/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/KeyVaultClient.java#L586):

```
public ServiceFuture<KeyOperationResult> encryptAsync(String keyIdentifier, JsonWebKeyEncryptionAlgorithm algorithm, byte[] value, final ServiceCallback<KeyOperationResult> serviceCallback) {
        KeyIdentifier id = new KeyIdentifier(keyIdentifier);
        return innerKeyVaultClient.encryptAsync(id.vault, id.name, id.version == null ? "" : id.version, algorithm, value, serviceCallback);
    }
```

Observe the parameters required in this method, and it's not difficult to find that it needs the parameters of the byte[] type, so you just have to convert object to byte[].

You can refer to the code which mentioned in the SO thread:[Java Serializable Object to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(yourObject);
  out.flush();
  byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
  ...
} finally {
  try {
    bos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ignore close exception
  }
}
```