# How can I convert a Kotlin lambda to a String and back to a lambda?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, lambda

How can I convert `() -> Unit` to a String and back to an executable method? From what I've seen so far lambdas in Kotlin are Serializables, which should be half way to the solution, but I cannot figure out how to make this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

If the only constraint is that the result be a `String`, then you can actually [serialize the instance of the function type to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array) and convert it to a `String` in any way that will let you do the reverse, such as encode it with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Here's how you encode it:

```
val f: (Int) -> Int = { it * 2 }
val serialized = ByteArrayOutputStream().run {
    ObjectOutputStream(this).apply { writeObject(f) }
    toByteArray()
}
val string = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(serialized)
```

And here's how to decode it back:

```
val decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string)

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val deserialized: (Int) -> Int =
    ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(decoded))
        .readObject() as (Int) -> Int
```

Here's a complete runnable example: [(link)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Note that for this to work, the side that decodes the string to a function instance must have the same class loaded for the lambda as the side that encoded it, as otherwise deserializing it will likely fail.