# Send two Serialized Java objects under one Kafka Topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement Kafka Consumer and Producer which sends and receives Java Objects. Full [Source](https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test) I tried this:

***Producer:***

```
    @Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> producerFactory, ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = factory.createContainer("tp-sale");
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("tp-sale.reply");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, kafkaMessageListenerContainer);
    }
}
```

***Send object:***

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/checkout")
public class CheckoutController {
    
    private TransactionService transactionService;
    private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> requestReplyKafkaTemplate;
    private static String topic = "tp-sale";

    @Autowired
    public CheckoutController(ValidationMessage validationMessage, TransactionService transactionService,
                              KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate,
                              ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> requestReplyKafkaTemplate){
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
        this.saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;
        this.requestReplyKafkaTemplate = requestReplyKafkaTemplate;
    }

    @PostMapping("test")
    private void performPayment() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setStatus(PaymentTransactionStatus.IN_PROGRESS.getText());

        Transaction insertedTransaction = transactionService.save(transaction);

        SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
        obj.setId(100);

        ProducerRecord<String, SaleRequestFactory> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-sale", obj);
        RequestReplyFuture<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyFuture = requestReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ConsumerRecord<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        SaleResponseFactory value = consumerRecord.value();
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! " + value.getUnique_id());
    }
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

***Receive Object***

```
@Component
public class ProcessingSaleListener {

    private static String topic = "tp-sale";

    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
    public SaleResponseFactory process(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(tf.getId());

        SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
        resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

        return resObj;
    }
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private int id;

}
```

***Serializer***

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

***Response Object***

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;

    private String unique_id;
}
```

***Response Class***

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleRequestFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data)
    {
        SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleRequestFactory = (SaleRequestFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
        }
        return saleRequestFactory;
    }
}
```

I want to send and receive different Serialized Java Object based on the Object type. For example sometimes `SaleRequestFactory` and to receive `SaleResponseFactory` or to send `AuthRequestFactory` and receive `AuthResponseFactory`. Is it possible to send and receive diffrent Java Obects using one topic?

Full example [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test)

Comment: I don't know how to implement the code. Can you show me please? It's not clear for me how to configure the Consumer and Producer for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object` as the value type - here is an example using Boot's auto-configured infrastructure beans...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65866763Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65866763Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so65866763", new Foo());
            template.send("so65866763", new Bar());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so65866763").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}

class Foo implements Serializable {

}

class Bar implements Serializable {

}

@Component
@KafkaListener(id = "so65866763", topics = "so65866763")
class Listener {

    @KafkaHandler
    void fooListener(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println("In fooListener: " + foo);
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    void barListener(Bar bar) {
        System.out.println("In barListener: " + bar);
    }

}
```

```java
public class JavaSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Headers headers, Object data) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
            oos.writeObject(data);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public class JavaDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
            return ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=com.example.demo.JavaSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.example.demo.JavaDeserializer
```

```
In fooListener: com.example.demo.Foo@331ca660
In barListener: com.example.demo.Bar@26f54288
```

Comment: Very good answer Gary! I'm interested to ask you if I use this approach what might be the advantages/downsides for Kafka? For now the advantage that I can think of is that it will consume less resources and will be quicker than JSON type payload. What do you think?

Comment: The biggest disadvantage of this approach is that Java serialization tightly couples the producer and consumer (same classes needed on both class paths). With JSON, they can be completely different (but compatible) types; furthermore, non-java applications can consume/produce JSON. There are other polyglot technologies too, e.g. Google Protocol Buffers, Avro, etc.

Comment: In my case the entire app will be 100% Java. So this is not a problem. Have you used Google Protocol Buffers, Avro? Can you share opinion why it's better to use them?

Comment: I don't, but there are lots of opinions on the internet.

Comment: I see one limitation. Into your example Object is send without reply. I need to return back `ReplyObject` which is different for every `@KafkaHandler`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. They can have different return types.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you need two separate producer factories for each object type. Or one with ByteArraySerializer and serialize objects yourself (equivalently, Gary's answer)

Same for the consumer if you actually want to get the object deserialized correctly. Otherwise, you would use the ByteArrayDeserializer (again, equivalent to Gary's shown deserializer), then assuming Java were unable to determine what object types are in the bytes (which serialized Object Streams are}, you'd include extra metadata in the record, such as headers, or a specific key that you parse to determine how to deserialize the data, then call the respective deserialize method yourself

Overall, I suggest re-evaluating why you need to put different types of records in one topic, or look at alternative message formats, including something like the CloudEvents spec, or use Avro / Protobuf / polymorphic JSON types, which would work better to use with clients other than Kafka

Comment: Of what? `new ProducerRecord<>("topic", serializer.serialize(obj));`?

Comment: And `@KafkaListener... process(@Payload byte[] data...)` with call to `deserializer.deserialize(data)`?

Comment: Here is the description of the design problem that I face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811681/design-kafka-consumers-and-producers-for-scalability Can you show me how to implement this with separate producer factories, please?

Comment: Since you are using Java serialization, you don't need 2 factories; just use `Object` as the value type. On the receiver side, use a class-level `@KafkaListener` with a `@KafkaHandler` method for each type and the framework will take care of the routing. See my answer for an example.