# Convert a generic type value to byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

**Background**

Building following class

```
public class DerivedClass<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
    
      @Override
      public void invoke(T value, Context context) throws Exception {
                //Send data to Kafka
                // Need to covert to byte[]
      }
}
```

**Problem**

Not sure if this makes sense, but need to convert this value to byte array
e.g. In case of String, it is possible using `getBytes()` method. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Serializable Object to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array)

Comment: Also, here's [a basic tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-an-object-to-byte-array-in-java) for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getBytes() is a method specific to String so you need a more general way to convert objects, not just Strings, to a Byte array. This post seems to explain how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836659/6630965.

I believe this can only be done on objects that implement Serializable though, so you'll probably want to specify that in your generic type, like this:

```
DerivedClass<T extends Serializable>
```