# How to read bytes type from bigquery in Java?

Tags: python, java, google-bigquery, pickle

We have a legacy dataflow job in Scala which basically reads from Bigquery and then dumps it into Postgres. 
In Scala we read from bigquery, map it onto a case class and then dump it into Postgres, and it works perfectly for bigquery's `Bytes` type as well.
The Schema we read from BQ into has an `Array[Byte]` field in Scala, we use `.setBytes` function to dump it into postgres table in the relevant `Bytea` column.

Now we are migrating that job to Java, we are not using type case classes this time and the read from bigquery returns as `com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow` object, for all the other field types it works as expected but I am having issues with the `Bytes` type.

When I do

```
insetQuery.setBytes(3, row.get('bytes_type_column'))
```

it says that `setBytes` column expects bytes, while `row.get('bytes_type_column')` is an object. Now, if I do `row.get('bytes_type_column').toString().getBytes()`, it works fine but it seems like the content of the original bytes columns is changed and I can not use it after reading from Postgres.
It seems to me that `.toString()` messes up the bytes and changes into some Java string converting which to bytes messes up the original form.

The other approach I tried was

```
insetQuery.setBytes(3, (byte[])row.get('bytes_type_column'))
```

which also seems to have changed the content of the column.
Had the same issue when I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836659/10190191).

I have almost no experience with Java, can someone guide me here on how can I dump the BQ's byte column value I read as it is into Postgres without changing anything in it?
Thanks.

If it's helpful for anyone, the BQ's byte column is actually a [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) python object, which I want to dump in Postgres, and then unpickle after reading in a Python application, if it's not being unpickled it means it wasn't dumped as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After snooping around the internet looking for the solution and going deep into the official repositories & examples, I finally found the solution for this [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/93cc031aedba12401c40ed92225d9885feb4415a/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/snippets/transforms/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryMyData.java#L71).

Basically, you will have to first do this:

```
byte[] bytes_type_column = Base64.getDecoder().decode((String) row.get("bytes_type_column"));
```

and then add it to your query

```
insetQuery.setBytes(3, bytes_type_column)
```